# Limit to API keys per project on google cloud

Tags: google-api, api-key

In order to organize usage of my sites through the dashboard on the google cloud platform I would like to assign individual api keys, one per site. I know that a billing account has a limit of 5 projects, but can a project have any number of keys?

Comment: The limit is 300 API keys per project as of today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using hundreds of keys now. This seems a project can have unlimited number of keys.

Only the queries per second (QPS) is limited by API: https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#usage_apis

Number of queries per day is not limited, it's just your billing.

Comment: Are the QPS limits per key or per project or even per your entire account?

Comment: @chrisan Did you figure out if the limits are per key or per project?

Comment: I have not verified the answers provided as I was(and still am) under 100.  The 300 john said was more than enough and I figured if I hit a limit I'd be at a sales point with google to actually talk to a human about getting more :) @FrankfromDenmark